# Highliting the Range Where Col"A" <> ""

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have been trying to develop a code which highlights the Range(A to M) where `Col"A" <> ""` but my code just highlights the ColA how to add the range to code.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub formatcell()

Dim Report As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set Report = ActiveSheet
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow

If Report.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
Report.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)

End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Report.Range(Report.Cells(i, 1),Report.Cells(i, 13)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 217, 102)`

Comment: Or `Report.Cells(i, 1).Resize( , 13).Interior  ...`

Comment: Thank you both of you its working like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
   
Set ws = ActiveSheet
On Error Resume Next 'skip error if no values
Set rng = ws.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Application.Intersect(rng.EntireRow, ws.Range("A:M")).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
```

Comment: Its very different but perfect. Thanks @Tim Williams